# difference between way a[i] and *(a+1) are handled

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

```
file 1:
int mango[100];

file 2:
extern int *mango;
...
/* some code that references mango[i] */
```

When both are accessed as `*(mango+i)` why do we get error?

Also if `char mango[5];` then array starts at location mango such that `mango=&mango[0]`. So variable 'mango' contains address to itself or the first character of array?

Comment: Well for one, `a[i]` is a variable offset and `*(a+1)` is a fixed offset :P

Comment: Instead of describing it, post the actual code that gives the error or shows the behavior you're talking about.  As it stands, I can't understand what you're asking (but maybe that's just me).

Comment: is double definition your error?

Comment: c files where rest of code is present

Comment: Arrays are not the same as pointers, regardless of how the rules of `a[i]` being the same as `*(a+i)`. You have lied to the compiler when you declared `a` as a `char *` if it in reality is a `char []` , and that's causing you problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you define a variable `a` such as:

```
char a[5];
```

Then you have defined an *array* of five (5) characters.  The address of the first character, which can be accessed via `a[0]` or simply `*a`, is named "`a`".  The array is also called "`a`" because the array is named after the address of its first element, as given in the array declaration by the programmer.

It is not possible to change the address of `a` by assigning to `a`.  If you attempt to write:

```
a = NULL;
```

The error you receive should indicate that an *lvalue* (value which may appear left of an assignment operator) is required.

Comment: Can't we increment a so that the first element of the array is now the second element? I seem to remember doing this in school.

Comment: @Ziggy.  No, you cannot do that.  A pointer can be dereferenced with the array syntax (i.e. the [] operator), as in ```char *pa = a; pa++; assert(pa[0] == a[1]);```

Comment: Oh yeah! Time to pull out that textbook again I think.

Comment: @Ziggy: An array name is converted to a pointer in most contexts, but it's not a pointer lvalue; you can't modify it.  `a + 1` works; `a++` doesn't.  Section 6 of the comp.lang.c FAQ (google it) is an excellent resource (as is the rest of it).

Answer (score 2):

The variable `a` represents an array of characters, and as-such, it is a variable that is bound to the address that holds the value for the first character of the array.  When array-names are passed as arguments to functions, or used on the right-hand side of the assignment operator, they decay (i.e., are implicitly converted) into pointers to the first element of the array.  Thus arrays are not pointers, but because of the implicit conversion, they can be used like pointers in many C and C++ operations.

That being said, if you are defining `char a[4];` in one .c file, and then including that declaration in another .c file that has a variable called `char* a`, then the C-compiler is going to complain about multiple definitions of the same variable.

Comment: Well in functions both declarations are same. But with #include ... we get error as array and pointers access members differenty.But compiler converts both to *(var_name + index form ) so where is the difference in access?

Comment: I'm trying to understand what you're saying, but I'm a bit confused ... I would need to see some code to see what's going on.

Comment: from http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptrequiv.html                  Given an array a and pointer p, an expression of the form a[i] causes the array to decay into a pointer, following the rule above, and then to be subscripted just as would be a pointer variable in the expression p[i] (**although the eventual memory accesses will be different**, as explained in question 6.2). That what I needed to know